# Number of cores on NVIDIA K20 GPU in Mathematica

Tags: cuda, wolfram-mathematica, opencl, nvidia

I am using an NVIDIA K20 GPU in Mathematica. The whitepaper for the K20 states the following specs:

1. 2496 single-precision cores (192 per multiprocessor x 13 multiprocessors)
2. 832 double-precision cores (64 per multiprocessor x 13 multiprocessors)
3. 416 special function units (32 per multiprocessor x 13 multiprocessors)

However, when I launch Mathematica and look at the specs of the GPU after loading OpenCL or CUDA, it says that I have only 416 cores (I have attached a screenshot of the Mathematica commands and reported specs). Is this somehow related to the number of double-precision cores or special function units? Mathematica reports these specs before I tell it what kind of code I will write (e.g. double precision, transcendental functions).[image]

Answer (score 6):

It is much more likely that your Mathematica does not yet know about the Kepler architecture yet, and thus translates multiprocessor count into core count incorrectly.

Since "cores" are mostly a marketing invention anyway, you can safely ignore that number. Mathematica will still use the entire GPU (although a Kepler-aware version might still bring some speedup through other optimizations).

Comment: This is NOT a Mathematica issue. Mathemtaica communicates to the device via the driver API.  Mathematica is only relaying what, in this case, the OpenCL driver is saying.

Answer (score 3):

This is an OpenCL artifact, not  Mathematica's  issue.  Mathematica  talks to the GPU device via a   Vendor driver API such as CUDA or OpenCL. In this case the  information  is coming via a call to OpenCL's

OpenClGetDeviceInfo (.. )

with a request for CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS

The OpenCL driver is saying that it there 13 SMU's  which can each run 32 threads. Hence the number of 416 Compute Units.The OpenCL spec is vague about what  a Compute Unit is.  So OpenCl is giving the sum of SMU   * Warp size.  OpenCL does a similar thing on AMD too reporting 28 Compute Units for a 7950  which has 1792 stream units. AMD 79xx runs 64 threads per SMU.

Comment: Which is what I have been saying in my reply. If Mathematica knew that a Kepler Multiprocessor has 192 cores it would have reported the number of cores correctly.

Comment: So how could Mathematica  know more than what the device says about the K20?  Mathematica ONLY knows what the device drivers says about the device.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: since there are 192 cores on a single stream multiprocessor (SM), each SM can work on six warps (32 threads each) at one time. However, for some reason the driver API is only reporting compute units as one warp per SM. Could this be because previous cards (like my Tesla C2075) had only 32 cores per SM, and hence could only work on one warp at a time?

Comment: Almost. The driver API only reports the number of multiprocessors, but not the number of cores per multiprocessor. Wherever the number of cores is reported, it is derived from the number of multiprocessors and an internal table of cores/multiprocessor for known devices/compute capabilities. If the device is not known, only a guess can be made which usually comes from the most powerful known device in the table but (as you've observed) will likely come out wrong.

Comment: Note that in your screenshot the number of cores for the Quadro 400 is correctly reported as 48, which isn't even a multiple of the warp size. So it is clear that Mathematica has some internal knowledge about devices.

Comment: The screen shot is not mine!   What direct evidence is that the Mathematica has more knowledge that the public API in the driver?